# How do I query LDAP in GWT?

Tags: gwt, ldap

I am fairly new to GWT and have built an application to manage working times. So far it was convenient to register/create the users in the datastore manually, which made testing a little easier. Now, to verify a login and automatically create the users, I want to retrieve the usernames and the passwords by querying an LDAP server.
My problem is that I was not able to find any examples, tutorials or forum entries that helped me completing this task. My so far only hope of success was an example using the javax.naming package which turned out not to be supported by GWT.
My question now is: is a database connection using LDAP supported by GWT at all? And if it is: how do I retrieve the data I need?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Suggested edit (http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/54022 - possibly from the questions author) that was rejected:** The question was not how to connect to a server in general (RPC or RequestFactory) but rather how to specifically query LDAP in server side code since the package I would normally use in java (javax.naming) is not supported in GWT

Answer (score 3):

You will need to construct a remote service that the GWT client talks to that communicates with your backends.  There are several frameworks to choose from, depending on your needs. See the [Communications DevGuide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) and the [RequestFactory DevGuide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) for introductory material.

```
GWT client <-- XHR request --> Remote Service-+--> LDAP
                                               |--> Other Database(s)
```